# Why my variable instead of adding, it replaces all the values in the collection vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Class SPECIES
    Public Property SPECIESDESC As String
    Public Property SPECIESCOUNT As Integer
 End Class

  Dim speciesSpec As New List(Of BGConstants.SPECIES)
  Dim spec As New BGConstants.SPECIES()

  Dim result = bgFiles.GroupBy(Function(r) r.SPECIES_TYPE_ID)
  For Each r In result
      spec.SPECIESDESC = r.Key.ToString
      spec.SPECIESCOUNT = r.Count
      speciesSpec.Add(spec)
  Next
```

This code is counting per SPECIES_TYPE_ID. For example I'm expecting these values:

speciesSpec(0).SPECIESDESC = Fish

speciesSpec(0).SPECIESCOUNT = 2

speciesSpec(1).SPECIESDESC = Rabbit

speciesSpec(0).SPECIESCOUNT = 3

**BUT instead I'm getting these values:**

speciesSpec(0).SPECIESDESC = Rabbit

speciesSpec(0).SPECIESCOUNT = 3

speciesSpec(1).SPECIESDESC = Rabbit

speciesSpec(0).SPECIESCOUNT = 3

Whatever the last value of variable SPEC will be the values of speciesSpec(0) and speciesSpec(1), which shouldn't not be like that. I don't want to replace the value of  whatever is in the speciesSpec but just add more to its list. Please help me to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: This really comes down to how reference types (classes) work. The answer provides the technical answer but I like to use an analogy. Let's say that you are making a list of people by recording their name. If I present to you in a red shirt and you put my name on the list, then I present to you with a blue shirt and you put my name on the list and then I present to you in a green shirt and you put my name on the list, what would you expect? Would you expect three different people in different colour shirts to be in your list? That's what you're expecting your code to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does popping from one stack actually pop from multiple separate stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296283/why-does-popping-from-one-stack-actually-pop-from-multiple-separate-stacks)

Comment: Seems like this is fundamental enough that it should be a duplicate, but I'm not sure that the target I identified is actually the best target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there's only *one* instance of `BGConstants.SPECIES`, you just keep modifying the same instance in the loop (and re-adding the same instance to the collection).

Instead of creating and adding only one instance to the collection, add a separate instance for each element in your data.  For example:

```
Dim speciesSpec As New List(Of BGConstants.SPECIES)

Dim result = bgFiles.GroupBy(Function(r) r.SPECIES_TYPE_ID)
For Each r In result
    Dim spec As New BGConstants.SPECIES() '<--- create a new instance each time
    spec.SPECIESDESC = r.Key.ToString
    spec.SPECIESCOUNT = r.Count
    speciesSpec.Add(spec)
Next
```